# django clone project migrate error occured

Tags: django, postgresql, migrate, cookiecutter

"django.db.utils.OperationalError" occurred while setting using django cookiecutter.

config\settings\base.py

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": env.db(
        "DATABASE_URL",
        default="postgres://postgres:root@localhost:5432/instagram",
    ),
}
```

```
C:\dev\clone\instagram>py manage.py migrate       
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\krsai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 244, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\krsai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\krsai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 225, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\krsai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\krsai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 203, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\krsai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\dev\clone\instagram\manage.py", line 31, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\krsai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\krsai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\krsai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\krsai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 460, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\krsai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 98, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\krsai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 91, in handle
    self.check(databases=[database])
  File "C:\Users\krsai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 487, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\krsai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\krsai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\model_checks.py", line 36, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\krsai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1461, in check
    *cls._check_indexes(databases),
  File "C:\Users\krsai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1864, in _check_indexes
    connection.features.supports_covering_indexes
  File "C:\Users\krsai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\krsai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\features.py", line 84, in is_postgresql_11
    return self.connection.pg_version >= 110000
  File "C:\Users\krsai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\krsai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 354, in pg_version
    with self.temporary_connection():
  File "C:\Users\krsai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\krsai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 639, in temporary_connection
    with self.cursor() as cursor:
  File "C:\Users\krsai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\krsai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 284, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\krsai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 260, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\krsai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\krsai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 243, in ensure_connection
    with self.wrap_database_errors:
  File "C:\Users\krsai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\krsai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 244, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\krsai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\krsai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 225, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\krsai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\krsai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 203, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\krsai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError
```

I modified only this base.py part, but the "migrate" command is not executed and an error occurs. What is the reason?

1. installed postgresql
2. create DB name as "instagram"
3. installed cookiecutter
4. modified "base.py"
5. run "py manage.py makemigrations"
6. error occured

Now I'm using postgresql version 15, could it be the reason of error?
Because I tried to use version 14 also but have same error.

Comment: Try to check your postgresql database, is it work? This error is due to a connection to database.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the migration files, then:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```